# Unable to connect to ftp.us.debian.org:http: [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

Tags: debian, package-management

I am trying to do an `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` on my Debian Wheezy armhf system, but the upgrade is failing with the above error.  Networking is working, and my `/etc/apt/sources.list` is:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Some systems have trouble accessing IPv6 resources which can effect reaching deb.debian.org for example.  Disabling IPv6 has worked for me in the past in resolving the "Unable to connect" issue:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

( no restart or services required )

Comment: These commands should be run with `sudo`

Comment: This worked but I would ideally like to revert the change and see if it can't work with IPv6

Answer (score 1):

From your armhf system try to ping the 64.50.236.52 ip address.

```
ping 64.50.236.52
```

If you don't have any answer check your internet connection. On the other hand, if you got answer from this ip address ping the ftp server name

```
ping ftp.us.debian.org
```

If it doesn't answer, go to your /etc/resolv.conf file and verify it is properly set.

Comment: The error message gives the IP address, which means DNS is resolving correctly. The configuration file is `/etc/resolv.conf`, without the final 'e'.

Comment: Yes I can ping that address and connect over http fine.

Comment: Have you tried apt-get update or have you tried to use a different repo? for instanance "deb http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free"

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but now am getting "W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.au.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy_contrib_binary-armhf_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch"

Comment: OK I cleaned up some temp. files & ran apt-get update again, now I am getting "W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-armhf/Packages  406  Not Acceptable"

Answer (score 0):

OK, I modified sources.lst to be this:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
```

then re-ran update and upgrade again and it updated fine this time,.